# AppFog: PHP debugging

Tags: php, debugging, appfog

I have a PHP application running on AppFog. I'm having trouble debugging some issues I am having with my server-side code. I've been attempting to use print statements and then run `af logs <myAppName>` but the logs do not contain the print statements.

When I do run `af logs`, I do see 3 separate log files:

1. `logs/access.log`
2. `logs/error.log`
3. `logs/stderr.log`

I've tried debugging using `print`, `printf`, and `error_log` but to no avail. Is there something specific I need to do for my logs to appear in `af logs`?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your error reporting level. By default, php's errors will go to the err.log logs when using `error_log();`, but many applications disable error_reporting() to hide unruly code, so before your breakpoint, set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`